# SQLALCHEMY: how to connect to a database when one only knows the DSN?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have this simple connectivity problem:

Someone installed the right ODBC drivers on my computer, and so far I am able to connect to my database using the following code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYDSN')
cnxn.timeout = 3600
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

However, for many reasons I want to use `SQLAlchemy` and using the naive

```
import sqlalchemy 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('DSN=MYDSN')
```

fails miserably.

> ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'DSN=MYDSN'

I cannot find what is the right syntax here. I dont know the url of my database either. Am I lost without hope here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to give the driver name at least. See [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc).

Comment: thanks @9000 I see the docs, but still I dont understand what is the right syntax. can you help me out here?

Comment: @9000 - Sorry to nit-pick, but it's not the *driver name* that needs to be supplied, as that is part of the DSN definition. What SQLAlchemy needs is the *dialect+dbapi_provider*, e.g., `mssql+pyodbc://MYDSN`

Comment: @Noobie - After you establish a pyodbc connection in Python itself, what does `cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)` return?

Comment: @GordThompson it gives `Out[11]: 'Cisco Information Server 7.0.3 ODBC Driver'`

Comment: @GordThompson any idea what I should type here? thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: It seems unlikely that there will be a specific SQLAlchemy dialect for that product, so you could try one of the existing ones and see if it gives you any joy. If it was up to me I'd start with `mssql+pyodbc://MYDSN`. Failing that, `mysql+pyodbc://MYDSN` might be worth a shot. There also might be some resources over at [Cisco](http://www.compositesw.com/products-services/support/) (KB and/or forums, maybe?)

Comment: @GordThompson. Interesting enough, using the second option seems to work, but a simple `print(engine.table_names())` gives the cryptic `DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] Unable to parse query text:  unexpected token: SHOW.  On line 1, column 1.  [parser-2904201]\nCause: unexpected token: SHOW (1000) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135409/discussion-between-gord-thompson-and-noobie).

Comment: @GordThompson unfortunately I cannot use the chat. Any hints I can follow here?

Comment: So apparently CIS does not "speak" MySQL. Did `mssql+pyodbc://MYDSN` crash and burn right away?

Comment: `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://MYDSN')` runs without error

Comment: while `print(engine.table_names())` crashes miserably

Comment: I got that. I was wondering if `mssql+...` (not `mysql+...`) fared any better or worse.

Comment: `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://MYDSN')` works

Comment: `print(engine.table_names())` now gives `DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', "[HY000] Unable to parse query text:  unexpected char: '@'.  On line 10, column 32.  [parser-2904201]\nCause: unexpected char: '@' (1000) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having used a "raw" pyodbc connection to get some idea of what the DSN might expect to be talking to ...

```python
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYDSN')
>>> cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)
'Cisco Information Server 7.0.3 ODBC Driver'
```

it seems somewhat unlikely that there will be a specific SQLAlchemy dialect for that product. Further testing revealed that both

```python
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://MYDSN')
```

and

```python
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://MYDSN')
```

can connect, but attempts to use SQLAlchemy features like

```python
print(engine.table_names())
```

fail because CIS does not "speak" native T-SQL or MySQL.

You may still be able to use *some* SQLAlchemy features, e.g., for running basic queries (that rely on fairly plain SQL syntax). For the SQLAlchemy features that don't work you could fall back to native pyodbc. For example, instead of

```python
print(engine.table_names())
```

you could use

```python
cnxn = engine.connect()
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
table_names = [x.table_name for x in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE')]
print(table_names)
```